# Are there any hosting companies that are already setup and configured for TLD domain mapping?

Tags: multisite, hosting, domain-mapping

Are there any hosting companies out there that cater to users who want to utilize TLD domain mapping and WordPress Multisite? Or will you have to go the route of building, configuring, and maintaing your own server configuration with a service provider, like SliceHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [wpengine.com](http://wpengine.com/), they seem to be WordPress-addicted enough to provide, what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use almost any hosting plan with domain mapping. As long as your host allows parked domains and htaccess, it will work.

I use a shared hosting plan with domain mapping multisite and have not encountered any problems.